# How to convert embedded xlsx files or objects in word to plain files when saveing a docm as docx?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, conversion, docx

Dearl all,
I create lost of reports from a word docm template that contains also embed excel objects.

I usually hand out the pdf documents but i am forced to send docx files to certain recipients.

Inside my docm file i have lots of macoors and embeded xslx (excel) files which contain alot of calculations and forumlae which i do not want to broadcast. 
When i export to pdf this is a non issue. If i save my docm file as docx the macros are gone, but the the embeded excel files still contain all my formulas.

Is it possible to save my word file and convert all embeded xlsx files such that only the values (plain text) is left in the excel objects while keeping my formarting of talbes?

I do not want do do it manually as it is explained [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Embedded-files-or-objects-found-ddba9b87-ab3a-4075-b2f7-fcbd309ef004?rs=en-US&ui=en-US&ad=US)!

Thanky you in advance.

EDIT:

I want the excel file to not contain any of the formulae , but only the plain text such as if i would have pasted it as "only values" if that makes any sense. Another obtion would be to replace embed objcts by a picture. But this usually messes up the formatiing.

Answer (score 0):

Extracting embedded objects from Office documents is done this way:

- Rename the extension of the document to `.zip`
- Extract the contents of the Zip file
- The embedded objects are found in the folder `word`, sub-folder `media`.

For more detailed infor mation with screenshots see the article
[How to Extract Images, Text, and Embedded Files from Word, Excel, and PowerPoint Documents](https://www.howtogeek.com/50628/easily-extract-images-text-and-embedded-files-from-an-office-2007-document/).

Comment: I do not want to extrakt the data, i want the excel file to not contain any of the formulae , but only the plain text such as if i would have pasted it as "only values" if that makes any sense. Another obtion would be to replace embed objcts by a picture. But this usually messes up the formatiing.